# How to assign both external and internal static IP address to GCP VM/Dataproc cluster via Airflow

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-dataproc

We have a requirement where we need to assign an static IP address (external and internal) to GCP VM/Dataproc Cluster's Master node while creating via Airflow.

We know its possible from GCP Console, but not sure how it can be done via Airflow or programmatically.

Comment: You should add the code you have tried so far for people to be able to support you.

Comment: I already mentioned its possible via GCP console, but not sure how to achieve via programming/ airflow. This itself means I'm looking for guidance to achieve this task programmatically/Airflow.

Comment: I am just saying, don't expect someone to write full code for you. you should try and ask for help with what you've tried.

Comment: Are you able to assign a static private IP address via the Google Cloud Console GUI?

Comment: Not static private IP, but static IP

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass hard coded value to assign the static IP addresses.You can follow the steps below to programmatically pass the static IP address :

- Pass the hard coded IP address to natIP field in the script.
- Perform a request to get the static IP address.
- Extract the IP address and pass it to the script.

You can use static external IP address using this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address#list_ip) and  for static internal IP address you can check this [link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-internal-ip-address#promote-in-use-internal-address). For using the static IP addresses in airflow, you can pass the static IP address in ipConfiguration field.